dataLayer.push Not Firing on Purchase Event - Backend to Frontend Issue
I’m experiencing an issue with implementing dataLayer.push on my website, AdGPT.com, specifically related to tracking successful purchases for Google Ads, Facebook Ads, and GA4.
Problem:
I’ve added the following JavaScript code intended to push a purchase event to the data layer:
dataLayer.push({'event': 'purchase_success','Package_Duration': duration,'Package_Name': name,'Price':  price});

However, the event isn’t firing correctly. The dataLayer is set up in the backend, but it doesn’t seem to appear in the frontend, and as a result, the event isn’t pushed to the dataLayer as expected. This is causing problems with tracking in Google Ads, Facebook Ads, and GA4.
How can I solve it?
What I’ve Tried:
Browser Debugging: Used google tag manager Tools to inspect the dataLayer, but the purchase_success and the dataLayer event aren't showing up.

Try using this:
dataLayer.push({
  event: 'purchase_success',
  Package_Duration: 'duration_value',
  Package_Name: 'name_value',
  Price: 'price_value'
});

